# is filter method and if else are same?

Tags: javascript

I was learning filter method, but is filter method similar to if else or are there any differences?
I am expecting that there might be some difference between them.
And is it necessary to create a new variable whenever we are using filter method().
like let us say

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
const odd = nums.filter(n => {
     return num % 2 === 1;
}
```

I can also implement the above code using **if/else** but why **filter** method?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. Please provide some code that explains how you are using them. In the general case obviously the `Array.prototype.filter` method and `if`/`else` aren't the same but I'm not sure that is what you are asking

Comment: filter is not the same as if/then/else but filtering implies an if-test within it. `.filter` is more like a loop with an if-test in the loop.

Comment: You don't have to create a new variable, you can use the result as the argument to a function.

Comment: You should add your example above to your question. But then...what about it? Do you have a question about this code?

Comment: @StephenP Make's sense thank you!

Comment: if-else can do lots of things; filter is very specific, so you have a clearer expectation of what is being returned.

Comment: You want to replace the ternary with an if/else? Is that what you are asking? Unsure what you mean by replacing it with an if/else. Show that code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The filter method and if-else statements serve different purposes and have distinct use cases in JavaScript.

- filter is used for filtering elements in an array based on a condition, whereas if-else is used for controlling the flow of your program based on a condition.
- filter returns a new array containing the elements that meet the condition, while if-else statements execute different code blocks based on the condition.
- They have different use cases: filter is ideal for selecting elements from an array, while if-else is used for making decisions and controlling program flow.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const evenNumbers = numbers.filter((number) => number % 2 === 0);
// evenNumbers will contain [2, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

Let understand what is filter in JavaScript

**Filter** as name suggested it's filter you array or object as your requirement.

The different between if-else and filter is that
if else is condition that use inside filter ( map, for, for-each ) loop.

If-else is conditions
filter is loop

Remember that filter is always return new array. it not change original array.
It's make separate space in memory of you computer.

let's understand with example

let assume you have to available you game for person who above 18
and not more than 40 year then you use if-else-else

```
if (age < 18) {
  return false;
} else if (age > 40) {
   return false;
} else {
 return true;
}
```

This way filter is work and return true false based on conditions.

And for filter let assumed you have one array of object which have games name with age restriction.

```
const games = [
     { name: "game 1", age: 25 },
     { name: "game a", age: 8 },
     { name: "game b", age: 48 },
     { name: "game 2", age: 20 },
 ];

 const filterGame = games.filter((game) => game.age < 40 && game.age > 18);
 console.log(filterGame);
```

Here is this example we are filtering game where age group are between 18 to 40.
And remembers , there is no compulsory so store filter data into new var. you can maintain that array or object as you requirement.